# Any tool or way to do a Automated Unit Testing in .NET

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I am developing a ASP.NET application.I have done the unit testing for the application.But i fear that there might be some issues.So is there any way to test the application through some automated process which is a available in .Net.

Regards,
Jebli.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're asking ... Are your "Unit Tests" written for NUnit, for another xUnit framework, or are your unit tests manual? Do you want an automated way to run unit tests that you've already written? Or do you want a tool that will work out what to test for you?

Comment: I want to do an automated testing of the code that have been written already.

Comment: WOuld you like to test business logic or UI or what aspect of your application?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest taking a look at NUnit, NAnt, and CruiseControl.net.  Nunit will run your unit tests.  NAnt will run your builds and then unit tests.  And CruiseControl will run NAnt every time you check in your code while monitoring your code repository.

If this type of testing is not what you meant then you might take a look at the following tools to run tests on the front end of your web application:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/WebReplay2.aspx
- http://www.telerik.com/products/web-ui-test-studio.aspx
- http://highoncoding.com/Articles/367_Unit_Testing_ASP_NET_Pages_Using_WatiN.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) and [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) are a couple of tools that can help in setting up some tests depending on what level of testing you want.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to write the code for the test itself,i.e. what input is used, what function is called, what is the expected output.  You may also want to look at RhinoMocks for testing where you need to mock out an object for another idea.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2008 Professional comes with its own Unit Testing Facility.  I prefer NUnit myself, simply because I work with Java as well and am familiar with JUnit.  You can find a bunch of information on the web regarding the new functionality.  Here's a good link: [click here](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/vs2008/4819)

Answer (score 1):

If you have already written all the unit tests you can think of, and you still want to test the application further (maybe to hit all the corner cases), you may want to take a look at [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) from Microsoft Research.

It basically does automated QA testing on your code, attempting to hit all code branches as it goes. Each time it manages to hit a new code branch through some combination of input values, it auto-generates a unit test, so that you have a repeatable set of tests that you can run again and again.